# Jscript Add and remove printers from network

Tags: javascript, printers, network-printers

I've been trying to look up some documentation on jscript programming so I can write this by myself but getting no luck in finding the documentation required....

My problem is: I've been trying to write a jscript which would connect over a network and add printers.... Some of these networks have username and pw. So wasn't sure what to do now...

here is what i got till now

```
var WshNetwork = new ActiveXObject("WScript.Network");
var PrinterPath = "\\\\srvprint\LJ5_4";
WshNetwork.AddWindowsPrinterConnection(PrinterPath);
```

Any help would be appreciated. ty

Comment: Be careful about escaping your backslashes, the PrinterPath should be `"\\\\srvprint\\LJ5_4"` (with two backslashes before "LJ").

Comment: All of the wscript.network methods operate on the currently-connected network.  You won't be able to connect to a different network using these commands.  So - whoever the user is for your script - they would have to be already connected to the network for this type of thing to work - is that the case?

Comment: @maerics, good point but still doesn't work. 
@James, We are all connected to each other but would only require our username password for the network.

Answer (score 3):

Mine's slightly different and doesn't help with the password but, the way I do it is to set this at the start

```
dim varNetwork
Set varNetwork = CreateObject("WScript.Network")
```

then use this line for each printer

```
varNetwork.AddWindowsPrinterConnection "\\server\printer"
```

I use GP to set this to run in each user's start-up and just make sure their domain account has permissions to the printer.

Comment: How do you remove a printer?